# ROSARIA make error (jade)

Tags: catkin-make, rosaria, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install Rosaria on a brand new ros-jade-full-desktop install.

I have followed the tutorial instructions but I am getting the following error when trying to 'catkin_make' with the rosaria source:

```
Base path: /opt/ros/jade/catkin_ws
Source space: /opt/ros/jade/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /opt/ros/jade/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /opt/ros/jade/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /opt/ros/jade/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /opt/ros/jade/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/jade/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/jade/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/opt/ros/jade/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /opt/ros/jade/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/jade
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/jade
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/thiago/anaconda3/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /opt/ros/jade/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /home/thiago/anaconda3/bin/nosetests
-- catkin 0.6.16
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - rosaria_client
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosaria_client'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rosaria_client)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "rosaria" with any
  of the following names:
 
    rosariaConfig.cmake
    rosaria-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "rosaria" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "rosaria_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "rosaria" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  rosaria_client/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
 
 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/opt/ros/jade/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/opt/ros/jade/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3 with anaconda 3.5 build of python. Don't know what else could be relevant.

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222041/rosaria-make-error-(jade)/) by [ThiagoWind](https://answers.ros.org/users/25258/thiagowind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-12-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You seem to build only one package, `rosaria_client`, which has a dependency to `rosaria`.

You probably haven't put the client into the same ROS workspace, i.e. the same `src` folder, where you did the first build (see [1.4](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA#Install_ARIA_and_Build_ROSARIA) of the tutorial).

Put the `rosaria_client` pkg next to the `rosaria` pkg, and it should work

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1